# Counting the particular field from table

Tags: mysql

Can I get the count results for particular field from table. for example im using this query,

```
select id,retailer,email from tab
```

i got the result set,

```
   1  ret1 test1@test.com
   2  ret2 test1@test.com
   3  ret3 test1@test.com
   4  ret1 test2@test.com
   5  ret2 test2@test.com
   6  ret6 test2@test.com
```

What I need is count of (test1@test.com) as 3 times like wise. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the count of all email addresses in that table:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) FROM tab GROUP BY email;
```

If you want to get only one particular one count use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE email = 'test@example.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

To count a single email:

```
select count(id)
from tab
where email = 'test1@test.com'
```

or to count all email values:

```
select email, count(email)
from tab
group by email
```

Answer (score 0):

To group all of your emails together to count them:

```
  SELECT email
       , COUNT(*) AS 'count'
    FROM `tab`
GROUP BY email
```

If you're looking for just a single email address:

```
  SELECT email
       , COUNT(*) AS 'count'
    FROM `tab`
   WHERE email = 'test@example.com'
```

Comment: i have already changed and got the results as like your answer. thanks.